# How to retrieve query params from encoded url in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am able to get the query parameter if the URL is like below :

> http://localhost:4200/member/0?members=1&facility=1&field=name&criteria=contains&string=black

I am not able to retrieve the query parameters when browser encodes the `$`, `=` and `?` in the above URL,

The encoded URL looks like this :

> http://localhost:4200/ccm/member/0/search/submitted%3Fmembers%3D1%26facility%3D1%26field%3Dname%26criteria%3Dcontains%26string%3Dblack

Below are the piece of codes, which i have tried to retrieve the query parameters (works fine when URL is not encoded, but fails when browser encodes the URL).

```
this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
```

---

```
this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(value=> {
   console.log('here');
   console.log(value);
});
```

I am using Angular version `2.3.1` and router version is `3.3.1`

Comment: may be this helps you https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Comment: `constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
        this.page = +params['page'] || 0;
      });
  }`

Comment: @KishanOza, it does not work. Getting default value 0

Answer (score 1):

This is the example how u can get the parameter from URL.

url is something like this :

`http://localhost:4200/products?order=popular`

then the code would be like this :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Component({ ... })
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  order: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.order)
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params); // {order: "popular"}

        this.order = params.order;
        console.log(this.order); // popular
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `params.order` in the filter ?? does it retrieve all the query parameters from URL or just one ??

Comment: like if u have url like this `http://localhost:4200/products?order=popular` understood ??

Comment: Yeah got it, but not working. In my case i have `member`. So when i use `filter(params=>params.member)`, then IDE shows `facility` does not exist on `params`. If i remove the `filter` to get all the query parameters, value is null

Comment: u can use this function to decode url `decodeURIComponent(params)`

Comment: we can, but only when params in not empty. I am not getting value itself.

Comment: when u route from any page use function `encodeURIComponent(params)` and then when u get the params from url use `decodeURIComponent`